# "ОЧЕНЬ себе на уме" — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, выбор-слов, уточнения

Встретилось вот такое предложение ([А. Маринина. Личные мотивы](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=3406&p=71)):
*— Видит она! А вот я, например, ничего такого не вижу и не поверил ни одному его слову. **Он очень себе на уме**, этот художник, которого непонятно как зовут, не то Саша, не то Борис. Закрытый, замкнутый, дурно воспитанный...*

Возник вопрос: нуждается ли **себе на уме** в дополнениях-уточнениях (очень или не очень, совсем или не совсем...)?
Приемлема ли такая "конкретизация" фразеологизма?

Answer (score 1):

Фразеологизм *себе на уме* имеет значение "скрытный, хитроумный, обособленный". Эти признаки могут  проявляться в большей или меньшей степени, но, согласитесь, с некоторой натяжкой. Наречие *очень* рядом с фразеологизмом здесь используется как раз для выражения степени проявления признака.

Без наречия *очень*, на мой взгляд, предложение выглядит гораздо лучше, ибо фразеологизм сам по себе выразителен и достаточно точен семантически.

Answer (score 1):

Наречие ***очень*** и другие наречия , усиливающие признак, выраженный фразеологизмом, **встречаются часто:**

А во всём остальном ― **очень, очен**ь себе на уме. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 3 (1978)]

она несентиментальна, меркантильна и **сильно** себе на уме. [Марина Зосимкина. Ты проснешься. Книга первая (2015)]

Интересная женщина, но **слишком** себе на уме. [Н. Леонов, А. Макеев. Гроссмейстер сыска (2003)]

Наречие ***очень*** может не только семантику обозначать, но и является **элементом структуры предложения,** когда для его "равновесия", выразительности звучания и расстановки ударений требуется **дополнительное слово.**

Он был какой-то **очень молчаливый, неприветливый, болезненный и себе на уме.** [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)]

Здесь, к примеру,  фразеологизм вписывается в однородный ряд. Иначе говоря, выражение ***себе на уме***  должно быть "на своем месте".

Answer (score 0):

Звучит не очень, но нужно признать, что в разных фразеологических словарях ([здесь](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/9593/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5) и [здесь](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/973/%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5), например) попадаются подобные цитаты и Ф.М. Достоевского и И. Бунина. Так что даже не знаю.